# Summing attributes in Java from XML using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, sum, attributes

I have this XML document and I'm writing a Java code to make some operations on the document  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<list>
<client name="Bob">
<transaction amount="100"/>
<transaction amount="150"/>
</client>
<client name="Ruth">
<transaction amount="100"/>
<transaction amount="150"/>
<transaction amount="100"/>
</client>
</list>
```

I want to sum all the amount from the two clients and have the following result :

Bob : 250
Ruth : 350

For now, I've written this code :

```
NodeList nl = racine.getElementsByTagName("client");
NodeList mn = doc.getElementsByTagName("transaction");
int somme=0; 
    
    
for(int i=0; i<mn.getLength(); i++) {
            
Element transaction = (Element)mn.item(i);
Element client = (Element) nl.item(i);
NodeList nameslist = client.getElementsByTagName("name");
Element nom = (Element) nameslist.item(i);
    
            
int montant = Integer.parseInt(transaction.getAttribute("amount"));
total+=amount; 
System.out.println("Name: " + client.getAttribute("name") + total)
```

But it doesn't sum, it just takes the first amount of each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NodeList clientNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("client");

    for (int i = 0; i < clientNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element client = (Element) clientNodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println(client.getNodeName() + ": " +  client.getAttribute("name"));

        NodeList transactionNodeList = client.getElementsByTagName("transaction");

        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < transactionNodeList.getLength(); j++) {
            Element transaction = (Element) transactionNodeList.item(j);
            int amount = Integer.valueOf(transaction.getAttribute("amount"));
            total += amount;
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }
```

Here's the simple piece of code. What you were doing wrong is that you also need to iterate over client NodeList to get transaction NodeList.